# How to compare dates to make sure Google Apps Script is only sending an alert once a day?

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, alert

I have a script in a Google Sheet that is sending out an alert if a certain condition is met. I want to trigger the script to run hourly, however, if an alert was already sent out today, I don't want to send out another one (only the next day). What is the best way to achieve this?

I've tried formatting the date several ways, but somehow the only thing working for me so far is getting the year, month and day from the date object as int and comparing them separately.

```
function sendAlert{

  var now = new Date();
  var yearNow = now.getYear();
  var monthNow = now.getMonth() + 1;
  var dayNow = now.getDate();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('CHANGE_ALERT');
  var sentYear = sheet.getRange("R2").getValue();
  var sentMonth = sheet.getRange("S2").getValue();
  var sentDay = sheet.getRange("T2").getValue();

  if (yearNow != sentYear || monthNow != sentMonth || dayNow != sentDay) {

    sendEmail();
    var sentYear = sheet.getRange("R2").setValue(yearNow);
    var sentMonth = sheet.getRange("S2").setValue(monthNow);
    var sentDay = sheet.getRange("T2").setValue(dayNow);

  else {

    Logger.log('Alert was already sent today.');
  }
}
```

I think this solution is definitely not the best approach, but I cannot come up with another that merges the date into one. Only comparing the new Date() doesn't work, since the time of day will not necessarily be the same. If I format the date to YYYY-MM-dd, it should work, but then when I get the date again from the spreadsheet it gets it as a full date with the time again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Requirement:

Compare dates and send an email if one hasn't been sent already today.

---

#### Modified Code:

```
function sendAlert() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('blank');
  var cell = sheet.getRange(2,18); //cell R2
  var date = new Date();
  var alertDate = Utilities.formatDate(cell.getValue(), "GMT+0", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+0", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  if (alertDate !== currentDate) {

    sendEmail();
    cell.setValue(date);

  } else {

    Logger.log('Alert was already sent today.');
  }
}
```

As you can see, I've removed all of your year/month/day code and replaced it with `Utilities.formatDate()`, this allows you to compare the dates in the format you specified in your question. I've also changed the `if` statement to match this, so now we only need to compare `alertDate` and `currentDate`.

---

#### References:

- [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))
- [Class SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Hi Ross! Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! However, I have one problem. With your example, alertDate will always be one day less than currentDate... I'm thinking it might have to do something with the time zones, but I cannot figure it out... it seems so illogical. I read in 2019-07-18 from the gSheet and do .formatDate, and when I log it I see 2019-07-17

Comment: You're right, sounds like a timezone issue to me. You can change the "GMT+0" to any timezone you like, I just used that as an example.

Comment: I was trying to get the timezone right, the spreadhseet's timezone is the same as mine, GMT+1. 
So I ended up with using `var currentDate = now.getYear().toString() + now.getMonth().toString() + now.getDate().toString();` - at least I don't have to get 3 different cells this way. And Google Sheets doesn't mess with formatting since I getValue of an int and not a date. Still, thank you a lot for taking the time to help me!!:)